# String split with exceptions

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am splitting strings to rows by using comma as a delimiter.

```
for col in [col for col in df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains(">")]]: #only on colnames containing ">"
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(", ")
    df = df.explode(col).reset_index(drop=True)
```

However, there are a three substrings where commas are appearing "naturally" and should not cause a split:

1. *Data related to sexual preferences, sex life, and/or sexual orientation*
2. *Contract, salary and benefits*
3. *Procurement, subcontracting and vendor management*

I was thinking since there only are these three instances if there is a way make some exception using something like this: **"preferences,"**, **"sex life,"**, **"Contract,"** and **"Procurement,"**. Or some more elegant way of solving it?

Here is a example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col > 1": ["Personals, Financials, Data related to sexual preferences, sex life, and/or sexual orientation", "Personals, Financials", "Vendors, Procurement, subcontracting and vendor management"]})
```

And here is what it should output:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                 col > 1                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Personals                                                               |
| Financials                                                              |
| Data related to sexual preferences, sex life, and/or sexual orientation |
| Personals                                                               |
| Financials                                                              |
| Vendors                                                                 |
| Procurement, subcontracting and vendor management                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, but I'm looking to utilize the " to indicate that the commas inside should be ignored.  The answers below do not seem to notice the ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex pattern with multiple negative lookbehind statements inside `df.str.split()` to essentially say *"Split rows on `,` except in cases in which `,` is preceded by..."*.

To achieve this in Python it would probably be best to use multiple negative lookbehind assertions - Python regex enforces fixed width lookarounds so it's not quite as simple as a single negative lookbehind with clauses separated by `|`.

Using the phrases from your example to split on `,` unless preceded by any of the listed phrases you could use:

```
r"(?<!preferences)(?<!sex life)(?<!Contract)(?<!Procurement),"
```

Full code example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col > 1": ["Personals, Financials, Data related to sexual preferences, sex life, and/or sexual orientation", "Personals, Financials", "Vendors, Procurement, subcontracting and vendor management"]})

df["col > 1"] = df["col > 1"].str.split(r"(?<!preferences)(?<!sex life)(?<!Contract)(?<!Procurement),")

df = df.explode("col > 1").reset_index(drop=True)
```

This will give you `df` with the desired `["col > 1"]` values as outlined in your question a fresh index `0...n`.

i.e

```
                                             col > 1
0                                          Personals
1                                         Financials
2   Data related to sexual preferences, sex life,...
3                                          Personals
4                                         Financials
5                                            Vendors
6   Procurement, subcontracting and vendor manage...
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can temporarily replace the commas for those exceptions with something else (let's ay a `;`.
2. Create a list splitting by comma
3. Explode the dataframe
4. Replace the semi-colon's with commas

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col > 1": ["Personals, Financials, Data related to sexual preferences, sex life, and/or sexual orientation", "Personals, Financials", "Vendors, Procurement, subcontracting and vendor management"]})
r1 = ['Data related to sexual preferences, sex life, and/or sexual orientation',
      'Contract, salary and benefits',
      'Procurement, subcontracting and vendor management']
r2 = ['Data related to sexual preferences; sex life; and/or sexual orientation',
      'Contract; salary and benefits',
      'Procurement; subcontracting and vendor management']
df = df.replace(r1,r2, regex=True)
df['col > 1'] = df['col > 1'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('col > 1').replace(r2,r1,regex=True)
df
Out[1]: 
                                             col > 1
0                                          Personals
0                                         Financials
0   Data related to sexual preferences, sex life,...
1                                          Personals
1                                         Financials
2                                            Vendors
2   Procurement, subcontracting and vendor manage...
```